# Read object from form1 into a class vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to read the content of a textbox present in form1. So far I haven't had any erroneous problem I created a function that acts perfectly. The problem now is that this function has become too large to keep in form1, so I created a class, which I imported into form1. This class contains the function that was previously contained in the form1, now the compiler gives me this message:

> "ence to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

probably because he can't read the object in form1. 
I wonder, therefore, how to access this resource, I tried to import the form1 class like this:

```
Imports App.Form1
```

function of the class

```
public function Export()
     oSheet.Cells(2, 2).value = Oggettivo_1_1.Value 'oggettivo_1_1_.value is an object of form1
end function
```

but I get always the same error, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Why are you trying to import the form? Isn't it your form that should reference the class? You only need to pass the data by `parameters` or by `property`!

Comment: show the code where you call the function, you may need to instantiate the object first before calling the method, assuming the method is not `Shared`

Comment: Indeed you are right, but I want to just refer to a textbox present in form1, what should I import the class?

Comment: you should create the object in the form, then access the text box `Text` property, then pass this into the method

Comment: I entered a part of the function by updating the message, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Imports` is typically used to make `Types` (like classes) in a NameSpace available.  It does not make available an *Object Reference* which is a key part of the error message you got.  Since we dont know how or where that class is created here is the general way to go about it:

```
Public CLass Form1
   Private myClass As Class1        ' whatever you named it

   Sub Form_Load....
       myClass = New Class1(me)
       ...
    End Sub
```

Since what you have described indicates that the class is more or less a helper for the form, the class needs a reference to that form *and* has no reason to exist without one.  So, we use the constructor to pass the form reference:

```
Public Class1
    Private myFrm As Form1
    Public Sub New(frm As Form1)
        myFrm = frm
    End Sub

    public function Export()
         myFrm.oSheet.Cells(2, 2).value = ...
end function
```

Now your class can reference the form using the local form reference.    Since we  dont know how your app is constructed, this allows the form to reference methods in the class, and the class to reference things in the form.

At some point, if/when your app(s) becomes class driven or class oriented, you'll want to do something different.

Comment: So I'm forced to go to the manufacturer to read the content of a textbox in form1 this? There is no way to import something without doing all this?

Comment: As I described at the outset, Importing provides access to *Types* (Classes, namespaces etc), not *object references* which is what you need to get at runtime stuff like textbox text, grid data etc.